# Decreasing a number with sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I extracted the metadata of a PDF in a `.txt` file using `pdftk`, and now I am trying to decrease the `BookmarkPageNumber` value for each bookmark by an integer. The `.txt` has these lines:

```
BookmarkBegin
BookmarkTitle: Preface
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 10
BookmarkBegin
BookmarkTitle: Author
... and so on
```

I am trying to do this using sed's substitute command, and here is what I have so far:

```
// $1 is the source .txt file; $2 is the decrement
// __ is a placeholder for the variable with the original value
cat $1 | sed "s/BookmarkPageNumber: [0-9]*/BookmarkPageNumber: `expr __ - $2`/" | cat > metadata.txt
```

How can I put the original value in a variable, and then replace the palceholder `__` with it, within this same sed expression?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For that purpose is better use `awk` so as it support arithmetic operations

```
cat $1 | awk -v d=$2 '/BookmarkPageNumber:/{$2-=d}1'
```

Comment: Oh man, this worked perfectly! Thank you _very_ much!

Comment: By the way, what does the `1` at the end of the expression mean?

Comment: @netcentric According to awk grammar: An AWK program is a sequence of `pattern {action}` pairs. One, but not both, of `pattern` `{action}` can be omitted. If `{action}` is omitted it is implicitly `{print}`. If pattern is omitted, then it is implicitly matched. So it just the trick to shortage your function: use the pattern `1` which accept every line and can ommit `{print}`

Answer (score 5):

```
awk '!/BookmarkPageNumber:/ {print}; /BookmarkPageNumber:/ {print $1 " " $2-1}' old.txt > new.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Another choice would be to use the shell itself (using 5 as an example, change it to whatever the actual integer you want to substract is):

```
while read key val; do 
    [[ $key == "BookmarkPageNumber:" ]] && let val=val-5;
    echo $key $val; 
done < file
```

Or, you could use a tool like `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/(BookmarkPageNumber:\s*)(\d+)$/$1 . ($2-5)/e; ' file
```

And here's another `awk` approach:

```
awk '$1~/BookmarkPageNumber:/{$2=$2-5}1;' file
```

Comment: your scripts are nice but you are forget the task: change just BookmarkPageNumber, not all digital fields.

Comment: HINT to check variable is digit compare it with oneself plus null `[ $var = $[$var+0] ]`

Comment: @Costas argh, indeed I was, thanks. In that case, most of my caveats were not needed anyway since this should be very standardized data. Also thanks for the hint, that's clever but will throw an error when it fails, so I'd rather use `[0-9]`.

Comment: in last awk is overcontrol: is enough find the *line* with pattern not *first field*. Secondary OP ask for different decrement not just 1.

Hint make an error just in case number with last alpha but, of course, your are free to choice.

Comment: @Costas there is no reason to assume that the string can't exist elsewhere in the line so restricting the match to the 1st field seems reasonable. Good point about not being 1, I changed the format so that any number can be used. I have no idea what your last suggestion means. What alpha?

Comment: alpha mean [[:alpha:]]. So variables like `1s` `567sd` `1000pic` and so on fail to error. In other case it works well. And work well inside of awk script with every variable. Can check `awk -v a=1k 'BEGIN{if(a==a+0) print "OK"}`

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: I just realised that he wanted to decrease the BookmarkPageNumber by an arbitrary integer, which I initially overread, and my solution below only works for decreasing it by 1. However, I feel hard pressed removing entirely considering the effort I put into it:

--------partial solution only---------

In case you are hell-bent to only use sed, I have this 1 liner for you:
`sed -r '/^BookmarkPageNumber: /{s/([0-9]*)$/\1@/;:loop {s/0@/@9/;/0@/b loop;};s/1@/_0/;s/2@/_1/;s/3@/_2/;s/4@/_3/;s/5@/_4/;s/6@/_5/;s/7@/_6/;s/8@/_7/;s/9@/_8/;s/ @9+$/ UNDERFLOW/;s/ _0*/ /;s/_//}' $1 >metadata.txt`

Note: this only works for natural decimal numbers, I hope this is okay for you.

Oh, it even has underflow detection. So in case you want your page numbers to saturate down to 0, just replace `UNDERFLOW` by `0`

And I agree with anyone who calls this a mere intellectual wankery, because that's what it is.

p.s.: You should probably check that your input and output file descriptors don't point to the same file, or else the file will get truncated if the user is having write access.